# Android: can you add multiple childs to a LinearLayout in a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout

I'm creating a `ListView` where each list item has a `LinearLayout` which I would like to use to dynamically add multiple input components. I use the following layout for the list items.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
  ...
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

When I add multiple checkboxes to the `input_container` I only see the first checkbox. The `LinearLayout`'s height seems to be correct though (there is room for the missing checkboxes).

The result looks something like:

```
--------------------------
List item 1
[_] Option 1








--------------------------
List item 2
```

Comment: I found out that removing `input_container` and using the list item's root `LinearLayout` to add the multiple checkboxes to does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to use the correct Orientation.

By default, LinearLayout has a horizontal orientation.

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

So your xml will look like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation:"vertical">

        <!-- Your stuff here -->

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can read more about `LinearLayout` and its orientation here: [Android Developer: LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android%3aorientation)

Comment: You're welcome. We all overlook something trivial sometimes :-)